# Making sure my headless browser is in the right place in my Playwright + Python + Aws lambda setup

Tags: aws-lambda, playwright-python

I have previously used playwright with JS and life was easy since an npm package (playwright-aws-lambda) did the magic for me.

I cannot find anything similar for python so I guess I have to dig deeper but do not know where to start.

Is there a package to support for playwright+python on aws-lambda  or a fundamental solution to add a headless browser for this setup?

Understand that alternatives packages to playwright exists but that is not what we are looking for in this question

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using the python pyppeteer lib.

the problem is that playwright only works with specific versions of chrome.

code below worked

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from flask import Response

import os
os.environ["PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION"] = "1050513"

from pyppeteer.util import download_chromium, chromium_executable,         check_chromium


if not check_chromium():
    print(f"Baixando o navegador na versão:     
          {os.environ.get('PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION', 'vazio')}")
    download_chromium()



args= [
   '--allow-running-insecure-content',
  '--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required', 
  '--disable-component-update', 
  '--disable-domain-reliability',
  '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess,IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
  '--disable-print-preview',
  '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
  '--disable-speech-api',
  '--disable-web-security',
  '--disk-cache-size=33554432',
  '--enable-features=SharedArrayBuffer',
  '--hide-scrollbars',
  '--ignore-gpu-blocklist',
  '--in-process-gpu',
  '--mute-audio',
  '--no-default-browser-check',
  '--no-pings',
  '--no-sandbox',
  '--no-zygote',
  '--use-gl=swiftshader',
  '--window-size=1920,1080',
]
async def run(playwright):
    path_exc = chromium_executable()
    print(path_exc)

    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = await chromium.launch(
        executable_path=path_exc,
        args=args,
        chromium_sandbox=False,
        handle_sigint=False,
        handle_sigterm=False,
        handle_sighup=False
        )
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com")
    image = await page.screenshot()
    await browser.close()
    return image

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        playwright.chromium
        return await run(playwright)

def print_tela_google(request):
    image = asyncio.run(main())
    return Response(image, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Answer (score -1):

Selenium.
I don't know about your use case but I think selenium will cover it all.

In case you still want to use playwright, have a look at this repo:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python

Comment: We are actually moving away from Selenium and we want to use playwright in this case so the question is narrowed down to the playwright domain and the fundamental approach making a headless browser accessible on lambda

Comment: @Iman Then you should have stated that you don't want to use selenium. I have been running selenium + serverless chrome on Lambda for years and it work fine. I have updated my answer if you still want to use playwright.

Comment: We do use playwright for python. what we are looking for here is the missing piece where the headless browser should work in an aws lambda setup.  Clarified my question however, the answer provided is not an answer to this topic

Comment: @Iman you can use chromedriver + headless chrome (or chrome binary if the size is too large for lambda), pack them all and deploy to lambda